# CardLayout focus java

Tags: java, swing, focus, cardlayout

I'm trying to get my keyboard input to work, however it is not detecting anything - probably because I'm using CardLayout and i'm not setting the focus properly when I call the `show()` function.

Currently, it looks like this.

```
    containerPanel.add(new GameArea(), "newGameArea");
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout)(containerPanel.getLayout());
        //containerPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
        cl.show(containerPanel, "newGameArea");
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you getting your InputMap for your key bindings? Which condition are you using? I would recommend using `JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW`. for example: `myComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` Then focus stops becoming a major issue.

Comment: Or are you not using key bindings but rather using a KeyListener (you don't say)? If so, then please use key bindings, since this is a Swing application, not an AWT application.

Answer (score 3):

- focus is asynchronous, then you have to wrap requestFocus to the invokeLater
- this should be works in the case that there isn't added another Listenet take Focus
- don't use KeyListener for Swing JComponents, use KeyBindings instead

Comment: @ToGetHer: Actually the first hit when Googling `java key bindings`. 1+